# Regex for timezones in SQL datetime objects

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I want to store my date-time objects with timezones as strings. And to ensure they are in the correct format, I want to have a regex as a validator. This is how the date-time objects are stored in PostgreSQL:

`'2004-10-19 10:23:54+02'`

Pretty self-explanatory. Of course, the timezone part is optional, so the regex pattern also needs to account for that. Right now, I am doing it this way:

`/^\d\d\d\d-(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) (00|[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9])*(:[0-9]*\+[0-9]*)?$/`

I am not entirely sure this is correct, especially the timezone part. Will this match all possible timezones that can be stored in a PostgreSQL database? Thanks for any help.

**Edit: I am not directly storing it in the PostgreSQL database, so I still need to get the regex right.**

Comment: postgres will validate all this for you if you store your dates in a column with type `timestamp with time zone`.  In fact, it will do more.  It will be able to efficiently store the timestamp in native byte format, which will be more efficient.  And it will be able to operate on the time stamps directly , rather than requiring complex string manipulation.  It is incorrect to store datetime data as a string.    I'd offer it as an answer, but you specifically say 'as a string'.  It's worth reconsidering that choice.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not storing it directly in the database, if that makes any sense. So I still need to get the regex right.

Comment: so really, this question has nothing to do with regular expressions?  You have an example date format and want help writing a regex that matches it ?  can you replace `postgresql` with the programming language you're using ?

Comment: @DanFarrell Hmm that makes sense, sorry about that.

Comment: on the regex side I'll offer https://regex101.com/r/NFGPYR/2 which matches your example.  You can add more examples of both valid and invalid strings to refine it if you like.  regex101 is a great site.

Comment: These things have been solved, there is no need to solve them *again*. Look for an ISO date parser.

Comment: "*I want to store my date-time objects with timezones as strings*" - that is a **really**, really bad idea. Plus a regex can not validate that you have a correct date. No regex can detect that `2018-04-31` is an invalid date, or `2018-02-30`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hold that values as of string type, you may try `substring()` function as an option :

```
select substring(str_date, 
       '([0-9]{1,4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}\+[0-9]{1,2})') 
  from tab;
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/QVNJWV98118)